# MySQL Multiple column index

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

Ok, I have the following MySQL table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `creditlog` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `memberId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `quantity` decimal(10,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeAdded` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `reference` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `memberId` (`memberId`),
  KEY `timeAdded` (`timeAdded`));
```

And I'm querying it like this:

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM creditlog where timeAdded>'2016-09-01' AND timeAdded<'2016-10-01' AND memberId IN (3,6,8,9,11)
```

Now, I also use the `use index (timeAdded)` because due to the number of entries it is more convenient. Explaining the above query shows:

```
type -> range,
key -> timeAdded,
rows -> 921294
extra -> using where
```

Meanwhile if I use the `memberId` INDEX it shows:

```
type -> range,
key -> memberId,
rows -> 1707849
extra -> using where
```

Now, my question is it's possible to combine these 2 indexes somehow to be used together and reduce the surface of the query since I ll also need to add more conditions (on other columns).

Comment: Is that you want to create index of (timeAdded, memberId).

Comment: I'm interested in figuring out the order actually

Comment: Did you tested that?

Comment: Tried adding composite indexes in both ways, (memberId,timeAdded) and (timeAdded,memberId). Both seem to improve the query. Not sure which one is performing better.

Comment: Check cardinality it would help you

Answer (score 0):

MySQL almost never uses two indexes in a single query; it is just not cost effective.  However, composite indexes are often very efficient.  You need this order:  `INDEX(memberId, timeAdded)`.

Build the index this way...

1. First include column(s) that are in the `WHERE` clause tested with `=`.  (None, in your case.)
2. Any column(s) with `IN`.
3. One 'range', such as `<`, `BETWEEN`, etc.
4. Move onto all the fields of the `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY`.  (Not relevant here.)

There are a lot of exceptions and caveats.  Some are given in my [*cookbook*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/) .

(Contrary to popular opinion, cardinality is almost never relevant in designing an index.)

Here is a way to compare two indexes (even with a table that is too small to get reliable timings):

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
(repeat for other query/index)
```

Smaller numbers almost always indicate better.

"timeAdded>'2016-09-01' AND timeAdded<'2016-10-01'" -- That excludes midnight on the first day.  I recommend this pattern:

```
    timeAdded >= '2016-09-01'
AND timeAdded  < '2016-09-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

That also avoids computing dates.

That smells like a common query?  Have you considered building and maintaining [*Summary tables*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-summary-tables/) ?  The equivalent query would probably run 10 times as fast.